# The POM for org.json:json:jar:20210118 is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, maven-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin, org.json

I am adding jar dependency in pom.xml file in maven project

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20210118</version>
</dependency>
```

but i got error: The POM for org.json:json:jar:20210118 is missing, no dependency information available

I am trying add that dependency

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json I don't see such version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version you added is not available in maven repository, find proper version on [this site](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json). For example, this dependency should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20220924</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion....  http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 is my maven version which version is suitable for this version?

Comment: @rangachimalgi yes, it will work